# How to match two digits in pregmatch?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-grep

I have return a preg_match to check whether starting digits were `9477` or not and it works correctly. But now I want add another condition to add `9477` or `9476` should be valid.

Here is the condition:

1. should contain 11 digits
2. should starts with `9477` or `9476`

Here is my code:

```
preg_match('/^9477\d{7}$/',$Mnumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternation between the two numbers:

```
preg_match('/^947(?:7|6)\d{7}$/',$Mnumber)
```

`(?:7|6)` is a non capture group that matches digit `7` or `6`. A non capture group is much more efficient than a capture group.

You can do also:

```
preg_match('/^947[76]\d{7}$/',$Mnumber);
```

`[67]` is a character class that matches digit `7` or `6`

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping in []

```
echo preg_match('/^947[76]\d{7}$/',$Mnumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `(9477|9476)`

```
echo preg_match('/^(9477|9476)\d{7}$/',$Mnumber);
```

You can also use:

1. `/^947(7|6)\d{7}$/`
2. `/^947[76]\d{7}$/`